# Can you find me what's wrong in my code?

Tags: python

It says 'EOL while scanning string literal'...
Please tell me what's wrong in my code.

```
import random
r = random.Random()

Money = 10000
print("You have 10000 dollars! You can try one round using dollars. Do you want to try?)
running = True
while running:
      cmd = input("Press y to try, or any key to go out.")
      if cmd == y:
          cmd = input("If you win, you'll get 50 dollars. Write 1 to 100, which is percentage, and amount of money you have to pay.")
      num = r.randint(1,100)
      if num <= cmd:
          Money = Money - cmd + 60
          print("JACKPOT! You've got 60 dollars, so you have ",Money," dollars now.")
      else:
          print("Oops, you just lost ",cmd," dollars!")
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's actually readable.

Comment: Spyder is a great python editor that not only would have found this for you but would have added the end quote when you entered the first. It also would have found some of the mistakes in admpicard answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is just a missing closing quotation mark in line 5:

```
print("You have 10000 dollars! You can try one round using dollars. Do you want to try?")
```

Additionally you have to take care for your variable types while dealing with **strings** (every input is a string even if someone enters a number) and **integers**, that you are using for your randoms and calculations.

So some things need to be modified as well:

- `if cmd == y:` has to be `if cmd == 'y':`
- `if num <= cmd:` has to be `if num <= int(cmd):`
- `print("JACKPOT! You've got 60 dollars, so you have", Money, "dollars now.")`
- `print("Oops, you just lost", cmd, "dollars!")`

Comment: there is no need of doing `str(...)` to a argument of `print`, print do that for you

Comment: @Copperfield: Of course you are right, obviously I am underestimating the power of python from time to time - I edited my answer accordingly!